# How do I implement UserPassesTestMixin in function based views?

Tags: python, django

I can implement `UserPassesTestMixin` in class based views,

```
class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False
```

but I don't know how to implement this in function based view? Thank you

edit:

```
def permission_of_user_for_posts(request,**kwargs):
    post = get_object_or_404(Blog, slug= request.GET.get('blog_slug'))
    if request.user.username == post.author:
        return True
    return False


@user_passes_test(permission_of_user_for_posts)
def blog_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BlogForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.author = request.user
            slug = form.instance.slug
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    form = BlogForm()
    context = {
        'form':form,
    }
    return render(request, 'blogs/form.html', context)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def email_check(user):
    return user.email.endswith('@example.com')

@user_passes_test(email_check)
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: it think it is a little bit late, but can you please see what I am doing wrong while changing that class based view to function based view. Answer is updated. Thank you